# In btrace, how can I print a byte array in a readable format?

Tags: btrace

I want to use `btrace` to inspect the byte[] value of a method return use the `@Return` annotation.

The byte array is actually a normal string encoded using utf8.

The class is like below:

```
Class A {
  byte[] method1() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I have tried **`printArray`**, but it only accepts type of Objetc[], not working for type of byte[]. 
For **`print`**, it just outputs the internal object id like '[B@4fbc7b65'.

Is there any other way can solve the problem?

Comment: as btrace has this limitation, maybe you can try byteman, which is also awesome

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an omission in BTrace (https://github.com/btraceio/btrace/issues/322)

For now, use "trusted" mode where the safety checks will be turned off and you can do eg.

```
@BTrace(trusted = true)
public class TrustedTrace {
  @OnMethod(clazz = "MyClass", method = "m", location = Location(Kind.RETURN))
  public static void intercept(@Return byte[] data) {
    println(Arrays.toString(data));
  }
}
```

Comment: Does "trusted" mode means we can invoke any static method to the object?

Comment: It means that all the protections are turned off and you can do whatever is possible in JVM. If a field/method is visible you can read/modify/execute it.